# ELSE IF + do nothing c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

basically I got a rectangle and I want it to stretch only to the height between -130 and 300 on the y axis. If it reaches anywhere outside the y-axis parameters it will cap at that height and do nothing. Is this possible and please let me know if you need more information.

```
if y coordinate = -130 to 300 
{
    then vguage = visible;
}
else
{
    else vguage do nothing (or cap size at the Height it reaches spanning from -130(y) to 300(y));
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do but you know an `else` is not required, right?

Comment: That's not C# code.

Comment: `if(yCoord >= -130 && yCoord <=300){/*do your thing*/}//else do nothing`? is that what you are asking for?

Comment: basically just want to know how can i tell the rectangle to stop stretching if y-axis reaches anywhere outside the coordinates spanning from -130 to positive 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used pseudo code, I'm going to guess at variable names:

```
if(yCoord <= 300 && yCoord >= -130)
{
    vGauge.YCoord = yCoord;
}
```

only set your variable if the yCoord falls within a valid range.